How can I do performance testing on AS2 with JMeter?
I need to test the AS2 protocol with JMeter. Is there a plugin available for this, or any specific configuration required to effectively perform AS2 performance testing in JMeter?
Is there a plugin available for this, or any specific configuration required to effectively perform AS2 performance testing in JMeter?

ActionScript is a language used inside Flash which was shut down 4 years ago, you can do nothing about it with JMeter apart from using WebDriver Sampler plugin to kick off a real browser and perform your actions there. Theoretically you can capture the Flash plugin's traffic and replay it using JMeter with increased number of users.

If you're talking about Applicability Statement 2 - it's HTTP-based protocol so if you're in luck and don't need parameterization/correlation you can also record and replay it. In the opposite case you will have to develop your own JMeter plugin using as2-lib

It was actually the AS2 protocol, it was just a typo. Otherwise, I'm in the process of developing a plugin and I find it complicated. Thank you for your feedback.

You can use the aforementioned as2 client library from JSR223 Sampler using [Groovy language](Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?) instead of writing the full plugin, it should make things way easier.
